# Ionic 3 - Signature Pad is not opening on android kit-kat when google map is used

Tags: android, angular, google-maps, android-4.4-kitkat, ionic3

This bug is only visible in android kit-kat version so far.

I am opening a signature pad from a page that has a google map. Html of this page is as follow.

```
<ion-content>
  <button (click)="openPad()">Open Pad</button> 
  <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div> 
</ion-content>
```

This works fine in my browser and other android versions I have tested. But signature pad is not opening in android kit-kat.

Signature pad is opening in kit-kat when I am not using any map in that page. Following html code works fine in android kit-kat

```
<ion-content>
  <button (click)="openPad()">Open Pad</button> 
  <!-- <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div> -->
</ion-content>
```

Help me fix this bug

Answer (score 0):

you can try to first disable the click event of the map
before you can click the button to open the signaturepad

```
public PrepareSignaturePad(): void {
    // Disable the map
    this.map.setClickable(false);
    //then call the funcation for openning the signaturepad
    this.openPad(); 
}
```

Comment: setClickable(false) is not working . It worked when I removed the map as this.map.remove(). I know it's effect the performance of my app. Please suggest a better way if there is any